# what to do if you enter the wrong bundle id into iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I entered the wrong bundle ID into iTunes Connect.  I entered AppName" instead of "com.yourcompany.AppName".  What is the best approach to handle something like this?  Would I change my info.plist bundle id to AppName?  Or should I enroll in the developer program again so that i can preserve the app name?  Or is there something else I can do?

Comment: Consider following [the App Stores proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores), if you aren't already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you've lost the app name. There are a few things you can try.

- Rename your app, don't delete it, then make a new one with the new name.
- Rename your app and then delete it. (Apple claims that you lose the name, but it might just be an anti farming technique.)
- Contact the iTunes Connect people and explain the problem. Perhaps they can help.

Remember that bundle IDs can't be changed, but names *can*.

Comment: had to remove the checkmark from the other post because found out that your step 1 is correct.  too late for me though.  i'll try to email itunes

Answer (score 2):

Just create a new App ID with the correct bundle ID.

Comment: thx, sounds good.  once i create the new app id, do i need to update the provisioning profile for my developer and distribution profiles?

Comment: Yes, because the profiles are connected to the bundle ID. But as Moshe pointed out, it could be that you have lost your app name. In this case you should get in contact with the iTunes Connect team.

Answer (score 1):

Bundle IDs can now be edited in ITC if no app has been submitted. Just click the edit button next to the Bundle ID when managing that app in ITC.